# Compiling GMP library on OSX 10.9 with c++ enabled

Tags: c++, macos, clang, gmp

I am unable to Compile GMP on OSX 10.9. I am not entirely sure, if the problem is OSX 10.9 specific but what happens is compilation is successful but `make check` fails.

Please note if I don't use `--enable-cxx` compilation and `make check` both succeeds.

The full error is:

```
c++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -I../.. -I../../tests    -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -m64 -mtune=corei7 -march=corei7 -c -o t-cast.o t-cast.cc
brew: superenv removed: -O2 -pedantic -m64 -mtune=corei7 -march=corei7
In file included from t-cast.cc:20:
In file included from ../../gmp.h:51:
/Applications/Xcode5-DP2.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/cstddef:51:9: error: no member named
      'ptrdiff_t' in the global namespace
using ::ptrdiff_t;
      ~~^
In file included from t-cast.cc:21:
In file included from ../../gmpxx.h:29:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode5-DP2.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/algorithm:594:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode5-DP2.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/memory:596:
/Applications/Xcode5-DP2.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/iterator:386:13: error: unknown type name
      'ptrdiff_t'
    typedef ptrdiff_t difference_type;
            ^
/Applications/Xcode5-DP2.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/iterator:413:56: error: unknown type name
      'ptrdiff_t'
template<class _Category, class _Tp, class _Distance = ptrdiff_t,                                                       ^/Applications/Xcode5-DP2.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/iterator:720:66: error: unknown type name
      'ptrdiff_t'          class _Traits = char_traits<_CharT>, class _Distance = ptrdiff_t>
                                                                 ^
/Applications/Xcode5-DP2.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/iterator:720:54: error: template parameter
      missing a default argument
          class _Traits = char_traits<_CharT>, class _Distance = ptrdiff_t>
                                                     ^
/Applications/Xcode5-DP2.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/iterator:720:27: note: previous default
      template argument defined here          class _Traits = char_traits<_CharT>, class _Distance = ptrdiff_t>
```

Comment: You should ask this question in the Apple Developer Forums, given both Xcode 5 and OSX 10.9 are under NDA.

Comment: I am not sure if solving problems like this violates the NDA. Homebrew folks are already adding support for various 10.9 things. Having said that, I have opened a thread in Apple developer forums and will update this thread when I get proper response back.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `__need_size_t` define and undef in `gmp.h`. It'll import `ptrdiff_t` too, rather than just `size_t`.